# Automated Deleting old AWS RDS Manual Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-rds

I need some help for having idea how can I do to delete the old manual snapshot RDS, someone have a script for doing this action?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you do not want to do this via the console because there are too many of them? Which snapshots would you like to delete -- _all_ of them, or just some? (It could be dangerous to delete too many snapshots, in case they are required as backups.) What is your preferred programming/scripting language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i need to delete only the old manuel Snapshot, for exemple the snapshot that have 30 days life.
about scripting i prefere use Lambda with python language for this use case

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do? If any of the answers provided was helpful, it should be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aws-cli gives you --query flag which can be used. Filter will be in the request, so you won't need to filter the response

```
aws rds describe-db-snapshots --snapshot-type manual  --query 'DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime<`date-30`].{snap_id:DBSnapshotIdentifier,db_id:DBInstanceIdentifier,snap_date:SnapshotCreateTime}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write a script that will:

- Call [`describe_db_snapshots()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_snapshots)
- Loop through the results and whether `SnapshotCreateTime` is more than 30 days ago
- If so, call [`delete_db_snapshot()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.delete_db_snapshot) with the SnapshotId

Comment: can i use this script with python fomat for lambda, and cloudwatch rule?

Comment: Yes, you can write this in Python and have it run as an AWS Lambda function. The Lambda function can be triggered to run on a schedule with an Amazon CloudWatch Events rule.

Comment: Thanks Dear John, i'll teste it and give you feedback

Comment: Hello, i steel have a difficult for this lambda creation :/

Comment: You are welcome to create a new Question, showing your code and the error you are receiving.

Comment: thanks a lot of John for your answer, i just posted new question with the code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64357939/delet-old-manual-cluster-snaphots-rds-using-aws-lambda?noredirect=1#comment113803687_64357939