# Delet old Manual Cluster Snaphots RDS using AWS LAMBDA

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-serverless

below the python code of my AWS Lambda, i want to delete OLD MANUAL RDS SNAPSHOTS by using it, and it still not working with errors, i need help please for debugging and correcting this  lambda script. thanks a lot of.

```
import boto3
from os import getenv
import datetime
from datetime import date
client = boto3.client('rds')
ClientName = getenv('CLIENT_NAME')
today = date.today()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    delete_db_cluster_snapshot():
    snapshots_marker = ""
    while snapshots_marker != None:
        snapshots = client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots(Marker=snapshots_marker)
        
        if 'Marker' in snapshots:
            snapshots_marker = snapshots['Marker']
        else:
            snapshots_marker = None
            
        for snapshot in snapshots['DBClusterSnapshots']:
            if snapshot["SnapshotType"] == "manual" and ClientName in snapshot["DBClusterIdentifier"] and snapshot ["SnapshotCreateTime"].date() < today:
                client.delete_db_cluster_snapshot(DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot["DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier"])
                
delete_db_cluster_snapshot()
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but you should remove the `delete_db_cluster_snapshot()` sub-function:

```py
import boto3
from os import getenv
import datetime
from datetime import date

client = boto3.client('rds')
ClientName = getenv('CLIENT_NAME')
today = date.today()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snapshots_marker = ""
    while snapshots_marker != None:
        snapshots = client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots(Marker=snapshots_marker)
        
        if 'Marker' in snapshots:
            snapshots_marker = snapshots['Marker']
        else:
            snapshots_marker = None
            
        for snapshot in snapshots['DBClusterSnapshots']:
            if snapshot["SnapshotType"] == "manual" and ClientName in snapshot["DBClusterIdentifier"] and snapshot ["SnapshotCreateTime"].date() < today:
                client.delete_db_cluster_snapshot(DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot["DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier"])
```

Comment: hello John i put the function with removing delete delete_db_cluster_snapshot() i have this error:
{
  "errorMessage": "'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 21, in lambda_handler\n    if snapshot[\"SnapshotType\"] == \"manual\" and ClientName in snapshot[\"DBClusterIdentifier\"] and snapshot [\"SnapshotCreateTime\"].date() < today:\n"
  ]
}

Comment: The error is saying that `ClientName` is empty (`NoneType`).

Comment: so i should replace('CLIENT_NAME')  by my rds identifier ?

Comment: `getenv('CLIENT_NAME')` is retrieving a value from an Environment Variable, which you can configure on the Lambda function itself (in the console). If you have not provided that value, then that would explain why the code is failing.

Comment: hi John, finaly my lambda work fine, thank a lot of for your help !!!!!!!!